# Browser audio output (Kubuntu)

Tags: browser, kubuntu, usb-audio

I am working on Kubuntu at work and sometimes I plug wireless headset instead of using standard laptop speakers. Headset works using additional usb plug so it is detected as a separate device by system. I know how to set it as a default audio device for most application (i.e. Amarok) but for some reason browsers (tested with Chrome, Chromium and Firefox) ignore this setting and play audio using embedded speakers. Why?

Comment: Same symptoms on my laptop. I couldn't solve it so far but I have one thing to add: headset works with browsers when I log in as guest. Maybe it's useful to know for the solution.